# Why generated javascript code (on base of typescript) gives errors, i.e. "class" statement

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I decided to use typescript instead of disliked by me javascript in some application that I am developing, unfortunately I am receiving some weird (at least for me) errors. I developed some very small "app" to check if error will occur likewise. Unfortunately they occur...

I am using AMD, ecmascript 6 and visual studio 2013.

This is my root html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script data-main="start" type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.1/require.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also some very simple class written in typescript:

```
export class trol {
    nazwa: string = "trolisko";
    echo() {
        alert(this.nazwa);
    }
}
```

There is no info about any errors or warnings.
VS transformed it into such javascript code:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    class trol {
        constructor() {
            this.nazwa = "trolisko";
        }
        echo() {
            alert(this.nazwa);
        }
    }
    exports.trol = trol;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=trol.js.ma
```

But when I run the "app" I am receiving some error: class statement is underlined in error message there is written that there is some error in syntax...

Below I will place some screenshots:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
 [![enter image description here][4]][4]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of ES are you compiling to?

Comment: @toskv Ecmascript 6

Comment: that would be it. try compiling to es5 instead.

Comment: @toskv I tried, but unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Does your browser supports classes? Show error message.

Comment: could you post the contents of your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: @Maxx: you are right. It was giving error in IE, but in FIrefox and Opera it works. Lot of thanks!

Comment: @toskv: thank you likewise. I changed to ES3 and on IE it works as in FIrefox/Opera with ES5!

Comment: that must be a really old IE version.. poor you. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You have the EcmaScript version set to EcmaScript 6. Please set to EcmaScript 5 as the browser you are targeting doesn't support it.

[image]

PS: Here is a free book that might help you more  https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html